# Build list of tuples from simple list

Tags: python, list, python-3.3

**This is what I am supposed to do :** 
Write a function to get a list of values L from the user and build from it a list of tuples in the form `[(a1,b1),..(an,bn)]` where `ai` are each of the values of the original list and `bi` represent its position in the list.

Example:
For `L=[3,2,-1,7,3,5]` the function should build and return `[(3,1),(2,2),(-1,3),(7,4), (3,5),(5,6)]`

**This is my code:**

```
a=input("Enter values separated by comas: ")
L=eval(a)
print(L)
```

Comment: Using `eval` on user input is a dangerous habit. If you know it's supposed to be integers you can do something like `L = [int(x) for x in a.split(',')]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `enumerate` and list comprehension:

```
>>> L = [3, 2, -1, 7, 3, 5]
>>> [(x, i) for i, x in enumerate(L, 1)]
[(3, 1), (2, 2), (-1, 3), (7, 4), (3, 5), (5, 6)]
```

Help on `enumerate`:

```
>>> help(enumerate)
Help on class enumerate in module __builtin__:

class enumerate(object)
 |  enumerate(iterable[, start]) -> iterator for index, value of iterable
 |  
 |  Return an enumerate object.  iterable must be another object that supports
 |  iteration.  The enumerate object yields pairs containing a count (from
 |  start, which defaults to zero) and a value yielded by the iterable argument.
 |  enumerate is useful for obtaining an indexed list:
 |      (0, seq[0]), (1, seq[1]), (2, seq[2]), ...
```